# How do you connect to a SQL Server database from within a dev container?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, containers, vscode-remote

I'm currently working on a .NET Core project. When I run the application on my local machine (Windows) I can connect to a SQL Server database using my windows credentials.

I am attempting to shift into using a **devcontainer** within Visual Studio Code, but when I run the same application in the container (Linux) I get an error:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll but was not handled in user code:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

I'm not sure where to go from here. What did I miss?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: @Igor: No. Like I said, from within windows (host) the code runs perfectly fine. Within my container (linux) something is not set up properly and it fails.

Comment: You may need to use SQL authentication rather than Windows authentication. Windows authentication only works on the _same machine_ or machines joined to the _same domain or forest_. Putting code in a container effectively puts on a different machine or domain.